# Passing data between service and directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The use case is simple, there is movie.json which contains the movie objects. Next I want to display these objects using directives which are nested movies -> movie. The mediator and data exchange I think best is to make as service.

Currently the problem is that the data gets loaded async but the directive does not receive the data model.

The code can be seen here http://plnkr.co/edit/MTkW1NujanzDFm7r2IHu?p=preview

Comment: This works,  no need for service: http://plnkr.co/edit/fZXCkg?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=` binding

```
scope: { data: "=myMovies"},
```

instead of `@`, because @ will cause your my-movie attribute value to be evaluated as a string.  I.e., with

```
scope: { data: "@myMovies"},
```

property `data` will get the value `movies`.  With `=` it gets the object.

The parent directive does not need to be required:

```
//require: '^movies',
```

In the `movie` directive, the scope that the directive gets has property `movie` defined, so you need to use that in your template:

```
template: 
  '<div>' +
    '<h3>{{ movie.name }}</h3>' +
    '<span>{{ movie.published }}</span>' + 
  '</div>'
```

<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8YhfGftllckothhB6gkl?p=preview)</kbd>